# Python mysql.connector.pooling ImportError: No module named pooling

Tags: python, mysql, importerror, mysql-connector-python

I am facing some difficulty when I try to run a Flask app. I get the following import error:

```
  File "/db/mysql_utils.py", line 2, in <module>
    import mysql.connector.pooling
ImportError: No module named pooling
```

I tried several ways to install mysql_connector_python-1.0.12 such as

```
sudo pip install https://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-1.0.12.tar.gz
```

Download the file to local and install it. Also tried running the setup.py and had no luck.

I am assuming mysql.connector.pooling is part of mysql-connector-python, but please correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks

Comment: please show your `engine configuration`

Answer (score 0):

On my Centos7 box, i installed the community-release repo and mysql-connector.

sudo yum update mysql-community-release
sudo yum install mysql-connector-python

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-installation-binary.html

Comment: @legalimpurity Yes we read it! But still it is not correct misusing answers for comments